# converting LARGE string to an integer

Tags: javascript

i am attempting to convert a rather large UUID string to an integer.

for example

```
var largeIntegerString = '235764967663239169'   ;
```

when i go to issue either **Number()** or **parseInt()** a value change takes place:

```
parseInt(largeIntegerString);
Number(largeIntegerString);
parseFloat(largeIntegerString);
+largeIntegerString
```

i see a different value:

> 235764967663239170

is there any way in jScript to convert this and not loose the original value, or perhaps "cast" it into an integer?

Comment: You're running into the limit of precision of Javascript numbers.

Comment: have a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER